# Numpy trapz printing list not number

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to print a value for an integral using np.trapz.

I only get a list/array of values instead of the integral.

```
l0=0.5
h=0.3
k=500
time = 10
dt = 0.01
n=int(time/dt)

def F(x2):
return (-k*x2*(1-(l0/(sqrt(x2**2+h**2)))))-(k*h*(1-(l0/(sqrt(x2**2+h**2))))-g*m)


force=F(x2)*array([1,0])
x2=linspace(0.4,0.75,n+1)
W=trapz(force)

print(W)
```

Comment: Incomplete code, lack of expected output (related to not being a minimal viable example), lack of definition of `F`...

Comment: Please add `g`, `x2` and `m`

Comment: Still not a MVCE and missing imports and indentation issues.

Comment: Your call to `F` is weird, since you don't have `x2` defined. Invert the lines `force=...` and `x2=...` and see what happens.

Comment: Please check that the code that you have included in the question is runnable.  Currently it looks like some of the lines are not in the correct order (e.g. `x2` is used before it is defined).  Take a look at the recommendations for a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Okey, so the code is runneble now. But when i print W i get a list of answers. I thought trapz supposed to print only the integral of the graph...

Comment: Not quite.  The body of the function is not indented, and `x2` is not defined when you call `F(x2)`.

Comment: ... and `g` and `m` are still not defined.

Answer (score 0):

The first value of `F` needs set by `trapz`. In your case `force` is not the function ifself to calculate the force, but already an evaluation for the point `x2`.